# Installing package with service account

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, software-installation

I need to install a software called nominatim on ubuntu. Following the [install instruction](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/appendix/Install-on-Ubuntu-16/),  I created a service account user with a specified home directory at /srv/nominatim. I know service account normally don't have home dir, but this one specifies a -m options.

My problem is, since i'm logged in as user A, and am not suppose to run installation as root(no sudo), i keep getting access denied problem when running trying to create things for this "nominatim" user under its own home directory **/srv/nominatim**. I can't really do a su because there is no password for service account.

what's the best practice to install?

I'm thinking of

- installing everything under my own home directory and move it to "/srv/nominatim" folder and then **chown** them later
- create a password for this "nominatim" user and then remove it later. will this even work ?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the `nominatim` user using `sudo` and run the installation as that user:

```
sudo -u nominatim -i
```